# Fastreport does not working from Getit Delphi

Tags: delphi-10.2-tokyo, fastreport

I am using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo Enterprise and trying to install Fastreport. But when it is done it does not show the components.

Here is what I've tried.

1. Installed FastReport from Getit Package Manager.

[image]

2. The installation succeed and `C:/Program Files x86/FastReports` is created with all these folders.
   [image]
3. I restart Delphi and when I open nothing happened, there is no Fastreport downloaded.

And My Delphi Library Path is as it was before, nothing about fastreport was added.

`Component->Install Packages` has no Fastreport trace on it.

I already tried to.

1. Install FastReport manually from `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\CatalogRepository\Fast_Report_VCL-6.2.1`. (same problem)
2. Add FastReport path to Library path (nothing happens)
3. Go to `Component->Install Packages` and open Lib26 bpl files.
   It shows this error for all files, already tried Lib26 and Lib26x64 folder.

```
Entry point not found for C:\Windows\System32
Can't load package C:\Program Files (x86)\FastReports\LibD26\dclfrx26.bpl
```

I tried more than 20 articles on internet since 2 days ago. Now I am running out of idea.

Answer (score 2):

Fastreport Team helped me to resolve the issue.

The problem was that while using Delphi 10.2 Tokyo version Enterprise registered. The Getit packages show me the FastReport 6.2.1, which is the version for Delphi 10.3 Rio.

They sent me a link where I could download the correct version for delphi 10.2. Join [Fastreport website](https://www.fast-report.com/en/) and in the bottom right corner there is chat.